# file corrupted when hash value is greater than 128 char in perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a hash that contains a  value which is more than 128 char , now I am storing that hash in a file through nstore function.

```
use strict ; 
use warnings ; 
use Storable qw(store nstore retrieve);

my $hash = {

###value more than 128 char
'a.key.value.in.a.hash.that.will.be.sored.in.a.file' => 'some.value.that.is.not.getting.stored.on.the.remote.server.strange.enough.if.length.is.greate.than.128.char.may.some.perl.issueee'
};

my $temp_dir = 'C:\TEMP\log'; 

nstore($hash, "$temp_dir/temp_file");
```

Now I am trying to upload this file through cgi upload function from local to remote server.

`http://localhost/some/api?file=file` on the local machine that generated through nstore

```
sub post  {


    my $q = new CGI;
    my $filename = $q-param('file'); 
    my $upload_filehandle = $q->upload("file");

    open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";
    binmode UPLOADFILE;

    while ( <$upload_filehandle> ) {
        print UPLOADFILE;
    }

    close UPLOADFILE;

}
```

The issue is if hash value length is greater than 128 than the file on the remte machine is getting corrupted and I am unable to retrive it back witrh storable retrieve function

Comment: do i need to upgrade cgi ? i am able to scp the file directly without issue  but when i use the upload function , seeing this issue.

Comment: You could try using `read()` instead of `readline()` (aka `<>`); Also, `$q-param('file')` is a typo.

Comment: Also, can you give a hex-dump of the file as it is stored on the server? `hexdump -C yourfilehere` on *nix.

Comment: I wonder how portable Storable's format is. Could you use JSON or YAML instead?

Answer (score -2):

Your example does not show nstore() being given a hash ref as its first arg.

```
nstore(\$hash, "$temp_dir/temp_file");
```

Comment: I am passing a hash ref only

Comment: `my $hash = {...};` *is* a hash reference, so there's no need to take a reference to it in the `nstore()` call.